# get list item by id

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list

I have a list:

```
List<string> theList = new List<string>;
```

There are a few elements in the List. And now I want to get an item by the index. e.g. I want to get element number 4. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

Just use the indexer

```
string item = theList[3];
```

Note that indexes in C# are 0 based.  So if you want the 4th element in the list you need to use index 3.  If you want the 5th element you would use index 4.  It's unclear from your question which you intended

The indexer is a common feature on .Net collection types.  For lists it's generally index based, for maps it's key based.  The documentation for the type in question will tell you which and if it's available.  The indexer member will be listed though as the property named `Item`

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx

Comment: +1 - The indexer is 0 based. (for context, other answers at the time had `4` as the index).

Answer (score 4):

To get 4th item, you can use indexer:

```
string item = theList[3];
```

if you prefer to use methods, then you can use [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) or ([`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx)):

```
string item = theList.ElementAt(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Indexer`  to get the Item at selected `index`

```
string item = theList[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the indexer:

```
string the4th = theList[3];
```

Note that this throws an exception if the list has only 3 items or less since the index is always zero-based. You might want to use [`Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) then:

```
string the4th = theList.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
if(the4th != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

`ElementAtOrDefault` returns the element at the specified index if `index < list.Count` and [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) if `index >= theList.Count`. So for reference types(like `String`) it returns `null` and for value types their default value(e.g. 0 for `int`).

For collection types which implement `IList<T>`(arrays or lists) it uses the indexer to get the element, for other types it uses a `foreach` loop and a counter variable.

So you could also use the `Count` property to check if the list contains enough items for the index:

```
string the4th = null;
if(index < theList.Count)
{
    the4th = theList[index];
}
```

Comment: @tux007: default is whatever default(type) returns, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the [Indexer Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
var fourthItem = theList[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it, access via array index.

```
theList[3]
```

its 3 as index's start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Indexer to get the Item at selected index

```
     string item = theList[3];
```

Or if u want to get the id (if accessing from database) define a class e.g.

```
    public class Person
    {
      public int PId;
      public string PName;

    }
```

and access as follow

```
     List<Person> theList = new List<Person>();
    Person p1 = new Person();
    int id = theList[3].PId
```